# Regex Replace Between Quotations

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am wondering on where to begin to perform the following replace in regex:

1. Read file (.cs file)
2. Replace anything between quotations (`"e.g:"`) with its uppercase version (`"E.G:"`)

By example:

```
string m = "stringishere";
```

Becomes

```
string m = "STRINGISHERE";
```

Thanks in advance,

Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not stated in your question so I'll provide a possible solution for single-line quotations:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string MatchQuotedExp = @"(\x22|\x27)((?!\1).|\1{2})*\1";

    Regex regex = new Regex(MatchQuotedExp);

    string input = @"""Foo"" Bar ""Foo"" Bar ""Foo""!
        ""Bar"" Foo ""Bar"" Foo ""Bar""!";

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
    {
        input = Regex.Replace(
            input, 
            match.Value, 
            match.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

For multi-line quotation support add `RegexOptions.Singleline` when creating the `regex`.

With multi-line support, the input:

```
// "Foo" Bar "Foo" Bar "Foo"!
// "Bar" Foo "Bar" Foo "Bar"! "Multi
// line" blah
```

will be converted to:

```
// "FOO" Bar "FOO" Bar "FOO"!
// "BAR" Foo "BAR" Foo "BAR"! "MULTI
// LINE" blah
```

Also note that this will blow up if *ANY* of the quotations contain an odd number of `"` inside. :)

Comment: Thanks, I altered pieces as I forgot about something critical, but it sorted me out for what I needed. Will +1 as soon as I have votes.

Answer (score 2):

Since a .cs file may contain comments like

```
 // Look, lonely double quote: " Take that, Regex parser!
```

what you are asking will be very difficult to do with Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string don't have `"` inside.

```
Regex r = new Regex('"[^"]+"');
string output = r.Replace(input,m=>m.Groups[0].ToUpper());
```